# How to read, write, and compute with binary numbers?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am developing a calculator with SBCL and want to accept and display numbers in binary.  Common Lisp's default reading and writing uses base 10 (i.e., decimal).  Is there a way to easily read and write numbers in binary?  If so, do I need to use different arithmetic functions to work with them?

Comment: Which LISP dialect are you using?

Comment: I am using SBCL for SB-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/numbers-characters-and-strings.html) suggests that prefixing the numbers with #b will tell the compiler/interpreter to treat them as binary numbers.

From the article:

```
#b10101 ==> 21
```

Comment: Also use (format t "~B" 123) to print a number in binary form. The example in this comment gives 1111011

Comment: If you want to output with a fix number of bits per number, (e.g. first as 8 bit, second value as 4 bit), you would write `(format nil (format nil "~~~D,'0b ~~~D,'0b" 8 4) 1 3)`, which would yield the output: `"00000001 0011"`.

Answer (score 7):

In memory, every number is in binary. You're just dealing with different representations of numbers in your calculator.

When you read your expressions, just convert the binary number literals into normal lisp numbers, compute the value of the expression and then print out the result in whatever representation you like.

```lisp
> (setq result (+ (parse-integer "11" :radix 2)
                  (parse-integer "01" :radix 2)))
4
> (write-to-string result :base 2)
100
```

That being said, you may also change the default base of how a LISP interpreter reads and prints numbers by setting the `*read-base*` or `*print-base*` variable respectively:

```lisp
> (setq *write-base* 2)
10
> (setq *print-base* 2)
10
> (+ 11 01)
100
```

Note, in order to switch back to normal decimal numbers, you have to also input the numbers in binary until you change the `*read-base*` again:

```lisp
> (setq *read-base* 1010)
1010
> 5
101
> (setq *print-base* 10)
10
> 5
5
```

Lastly, you may use a special read syntax in order to read numbers in bases other than 10:

```lisp
> (+ #b11 #b01)
4
```